# Comparing exit code: unary operator expected

Tags: bash, shell-script, git, test, exit-status

I have a list of git commits in a `.txt` file and I want to iterate over the commits. For each `COMMIT_ID` I want check them using a `git` command whose exit code is `0` or `1`.

Depending on the result I want to `echo` `true` or `false`.

But when running the script, I get this error:

```
line 5: [: 0: unary operator expected
```

The script is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
input="./commits.txt"
while IFS= read -r COMMIT_ID
do
  if [ 0 -eq $(git merge-base --is-ancestor $COMMIT_ID HEAD) ]; 
    then 
      echo "true"; 
    else 
      echo "false"; 
    fi
done < "$input"
```

Answer (score 7):

`$()` is replaced with the output of the given command, not its exit code. To use an exit code, use the command directly with `if`:

```
if git merge-base --is-ancestor "$COMMIT_ID" HEAD; then
```

Comment: To clarify a little bit: Output as in what's printed to *standard output*. For example, `echo hello $(echo world >&2) goodbye` will print `world`, then `hello goodbye` -- standard error still gets printed, instead of being captured.